# Constraints in Linear Programming Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

One firm produces both exterior and interior paints. The table gives the details [image]

Let’s call the variables in this model as $x$ and $y$ which are the amount in tons produced daily of exterior and interior paints respectively. The objective function is given as $z=5x+4y$ which should be maximised subject to $6x+4y \leq 24$ and $x+2y \leq 6$. My question is that how to make sense of this constraint equation where 6 and 4 are the tons of raw material available but $x$ and $y$ are amount produced which is a totally different thing. How can it be less than 24 which is raw material available daily. How can one multiply two different entities which is raw material and amount produced?

Answer (score 1):

$6$ is the tons of raw material $M1$ required for every ton of exterior paint produced.

$x$ is the tons of exterior paint produced.

$6x$ is the tons of raw materials $M1$ required to produced $x$ tones of exterior paint.